# Audio CD authoring w/o an optical drive?

Tags: audio, iso

I need to burn an audio CD with a few kinks, like having no gaps between certain songs. I know I can do this with cdrdao, but my Linux box doesn't have a burner. Is it possible to use cdrdao to make an iso out of my tracks and TOC so I can burn it elsewhere? I went through the man page and internet but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, because an audio CD is not representable as an ISO image.  The slightly longer answer is that audio CDs are represented by the "red book" standard, while ISO images are burned according to the "yellow book" standard mode 1, which adds an additional layer of error correction.  A program that burns an ISO for you will add this additional layer of error correction.  So you would need a different kind of program (analogous to cdrdao) in order to burn a red book CD.